# Mapping Windows key to activate Application menu on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking to map the Windows key to activate the Application menu on Ubuntu. I've had a look around System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts but cannot seem to find anything there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an entry in the dialog you mentioned, (System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts): "Desktop > Show the panel's main menu" - this activates the "Applications" menu (or did you mean the menu of the current application?)

It doesn't seem as if you can assign the "Windows" key alone - but maybe you can use Windows+z (or some key near the windows key, depending on your keyboard).